# How can i use ModelName.objects.aggregate(Sum('field_name')) here?

Tags: python

I need to use `Sum()` instead of

```
if name in ingredients.keys(): 
    ingredients[name] += units 
else: 
    ingredients[name] = units
```

but I have no idea how, because I have a long chain of relations. Here is my code:

```
def shopping_list_ingredients(request):
    shopping_list = ShoppingList.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()
    ingredients = {}
    for item in shopping_list:
        for x in item.recipe.recipe_ingredient.all():
            name = f'{x.ingredient.title} ({x.ingredient.unit})'
            units = x.count
            if name in ingredients:
                ingredients[name] += units
            else:
                ingredients[name] = units
    download = []
    for key, units in ingredients.items():
        download.append(f'{key} - {units} \n')
    return download
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def shopping_list_ingredients(request):
shopping_list = ShoppingList.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()
ingredients = {}
for item in shopping_list:
    #if item.recipe.recipe_ingredient.all().ingredient.unit is dict
    values = item.recipe.recipe_ingredient.all().ingredient.unit.values()
    total = sum(values)
    #if it's list
    total = sum(item.recipe.recipe_ingredient.all().ingredient.unit)
```

Comment: ty so much for your response sir.
it says 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'ingredient' in both cases

Comment: you try show print(item.recipe.recipe_ingredient.all()) to me.

Comment: <QuerySet [<RecipeIngredient: угорь, г, Тест Рецепт 5>]>
<QuerySet [<RecipeIngredient: барбарис молотый, г, Еще один чек>]>
<QuerySet [<RecipeIngredient: ежевика, г, Тест Рецепт 6>]>
<QuerySet [<RecipeIngredient: угорь, г, Тестовый последний>]>

Comment: I don't know about your data, If you want use function sum() you have 2 way is convert data to dict or list.

Comment: You cannot call a field at a queryset. You must loop a queryset and then you have access to a field. Pls show your models.